# JSON feed object/array specify root name?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I just discovered and I am very excited about this product... I've had some luck getting my calendar populated... however, I need some more info I cannot explicitly find in the documentation... How do I point to the root JSON object key name "events" if I return an object instead of an array?

If I return an object from SQL like shown here, the events will not be rendered:

`{ "events": [ { "id": 434, "title": "Slot 434", "start": "2020-05-20T09:00:00", }, { "id": 435, "title": "Slot 435", "start": "2020-05-20T09:30:00", } ] }`

However, if I return an object from SQL like this, they WILL render.

`[ { "id": 434, "title": "Slot 434", "start": "2020-05-20T09:00:00", }, { "id": 435, "title": "Slot 435", "start": "2020-05-20T09:30:00", } ]`

When using a JSON feed, how to I specify the object root name?

I should mention I am using the events url object:

```
events: {
  url: '[OUR INTERNAL API AND MSSQL SERVER THING]',
  method: 'POST',
  // extraParams: {
  //   custom_param1: 'something',
  //   custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
  // },
  failure: function () {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  },
  // color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
  // textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
},
```

Comment: "When using a JSON feed, how to I specify the object root name"...you can't. You must supply the data in the format fullCalendar expects. It should not be too hard to alter your server-side code to send the correct format. Either that or you must use the custom events-as-a-function feature to generate your own ajax request, so that you can customise how you deal with the response, and extract the array from the response object, and send the array to fullCalendar in the callback.

Comment: I wanted to send back other data alongside the "events" data stream... stuff that maybe is pertinent to the application itself, like "success" flags, or other messages...  To the best of my knowledge, at least in MSSQL, I cannot append extra data to a pure json array `[{}, {}, {}]`; however, I can append to an object, which would require the events array to be named `{ "events": [{}, {}, {}]}`.  Not a big deal though -- I'm looking into using AJAX, and maybe I'll submit a feature request or something :)

Comment: From fullCalendar's point of view you can just work round it by using the events-as-a-function feature which I think, from your other recent question, you already know about. That way you can download any data structure you like, and just pass the relevant part on to the fullCalendar, the rest of it can be used for your other purposes.